# Ways to refer to past time

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

Suppose I woke up an hour ago, when I am still in bed, can I say these:

> I woke up at 10 and it's an hour from when I woke up

Or

> I woke up at 10 and it's an hour since I woke up

Or

> I woke up at 10 and it's an hour that I am awake

I specially doubt the last sentence

Comment: I can't understand your phrase. When you make this statement concerning events of that day (at 11 o'clock), the time when you woke up (10 o'clock) is in the past, but you used present tense *wake*.

Comment: I agree with user3169. Though I think it's not your main point of the question, *wake* should've been written *woke*. If you want to think in the present tense, you may need to rephrase the whole sentence, like *I've been lying in bed since 10 o'clock* or *I've been awake since 10:00*.

Comment: "I woke up at 10 and that was an hour ago" is what I would probably say. Or "I woke up at 10 and it's been an hour already [since I woke up]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different things -waking up and getting up.

'Wake up' means opening your eyes after having slept for whatsoever time. 'Getting up' means get up from the bed [That said, if you wake up, you could be still in the bed, but if you 'get up', you must be awake unless you suffer from *somnabulism!*].

So, it's possible that you *woke up* at 10 but *get up/off* from the bed at 11.

If someone asks you at 10:59, you may say...

> *It's been (almost) an hour, I'm awake*

Or *informally* ..

> I'm *up* since 10 (o'clock)

Comment: Sorry! forget the first sentence, my question is something else, please read the revision of the question.

Comment: The answer remains the same... 'quoted sentence' tells it all. Why repeat the time when you can say that without doing it? "It has been an hour..." works. It tells that you woke up at 10 O'clock *in this context*.

Comment: Thank you, just as I didn't say anything about "getting up" in the question, you may want to remove the first paragraph in your answer

Comment: I think in your first sentence you need (or you could have) a *that*?

Comment: Ahmad, it's not needed especailly when you 'speak'

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> I woke up at 10 and it's *been* an hour since I woke up.

*it is an hour* does not work, because it just states time (one hour) as an object.
A form of *to be* is needed. See [**be**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/be):

> 1c) to remain or continue   ⇒ *"will he be here long?"*